Shell script not running, "No such file or directory"
I was following the procedure from Relsense SDK 2.0 Guide on installing librealsense to Ubuntu 22.04.5 https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/compiling-librealsense-for-linux-ubuntu-guide to install the librealsense. Though I was stuck at second step,
./scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh

but it only gives me this:
bash: ./scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh: No such file or directory

I suspected it was a problem with permission, and tried adding permission with this command chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh, though it didn't change anything.
PS: I ran
ls -l scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh

and gave me this
ls: cannot access 'scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh': No such file or directory

I have been stuck on this problem for quite awhile by now, so any comments on this would be appreciated.

Add the output of ls -l scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh.

Did you switch into the librealsense directory first? That step is only implicit in the instructions.

Why would you think changing permissions would help? The error message says the file doesn't exist, not that permissions are wrong.

Thanks @BenjaminW. that solved the problem. I really appreciate this!

You should report this to the developers, it really should be in the instructions.

Or that line should be librealsense/scripts/setup_udev_rules.sh
